# Intel XDK iOS build won't upload to apple

Tags: ios, intel-xdk

The Intel XDK build succeeds without error. However when uploading the iOS build to apple via application loader it fails with the following error.

ITMS-90046
Invalid code signing entitlements
Value '*' for key com.apple.developer.associated-domains in Payload/MyApp.app/MyApp is not supported.

Comment: did u use AppStore distribution certificate and provision profile to build ?

Comment: Actually I just got it to work. The answer to your question is yes. The answer to the problem seemed to be that the distribution had associated-domains enabled. When I disabled, it worked. However I do not know what that does and whether the app will continue to work so waiting to see.

Answer (score 0):

To install hybrid application in iPhone,you need to build the app with the adhoc certificate that contain the UDID of your device(Unique for each device). After build your application ,please upload the ipa to [this site](https://www.diawi.com/) and sent to get a link.Open that link in safari browser will open a popup to add application. Hope this help you